# Loading Spinner not showing while load a checkboxes

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, checkbox, spinner

I am trying to show loading spinner while loading checkboxes using below code in jquery mobile 1.3.2 on Android native app, but it is not working, can any one help me what the issue is and how to make it work

Here is my code:

```
function onChangeCarrera(idCarrera,idEvento){

    $.mobile.loading('show', {
        text: 'Cargando Corredores',
        textVisible: true,
        theme: 'a',
        html: ""});

    cargaCorredores(idCarrera,idEvento);

    resetMontoTotal();

    $.mobile.loading('hide');
}

function cargaCorredores(idCarrera,idEvento){
    var dom = jsel(json);

    var carrera = dom.select('//Eventos/*[@id='+idEvento+']/carreras/*[@nroCarrera='+idCarrera+']');

    //Muestra Label
    $("#lblCorredores").text("Selección de corredores");

    var html;

    for (var x=1; x<=TipoApuesta.patas; x++){
        html='<fieldset id="carrera"+x+"_fieldset" data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup"><legend>'+eval("TipoApuesta.p"+x+"Nombre")+'</legend>';
        $.each(carrera.corredores, function(i, corredor) {
            html+='<input type="checkbox" onclick="resetMontoTotal();" value="'+corredor.nroCorredor+'" name="checkbox_'+idCarrera+'_'+idEvento+'_'+corredor.nroCorredor+'"  id="checkbox_'+idCarrera+'_'+idEvento+'_'+corredor.nroCorredor+'" class="corredores'+x+'" /><label for="checkbox_'+idCarrera+'_'+idEvento+'_'+corredor.nroCorredor+'">'+corredor.nroCorredor+'</label>';
        });
        $("#carreras"+x).html(html+'</fieldset');
        $("#carreras"+x).trigger("create");
    }

    if (TipoApuesta.patas<4){
        for (var j=4; j>TipoApuesta.patas; j--){
            $("#carreras"+j).html('');
            $("#carreras"+j).trigger("create");
        }
    }

}
```

I'm using a json preloaded with the page to make a checkboxes. 
Many thanks!

Comment: if you move it outside the function, does it show? this only happens in android?

Comment: happens in android and pc browser. do you means move the $.mobile.loading('show') outside?

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere about needing to use interval variables.  I had the same issue and this resolved it, although it's a little "hacky" to me.

```
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        $.mobile.loading('show', {
            text: 'Resuming...',
            textVisible: true,
            theme: 'a',
            html: ""
        });
        clearInterval(interval);
    }, 1);
```

I had to use a different variable name for interval on each of my app's pages.